# Weird data output about PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

It's wired that only Field name is correct but others. I can't get the the expected result from the code.
How get the correct meta data from the database?
[The expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dESiN.jpg)

[Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asWKY.jpg)

```
<?php
     // Open a connection to the server and USE the winestore
       $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","winestore");

       /* check connection */
       if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
       {
           printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
           exit();
       }

       // Run a query on the wine table in the winestore database to retrieve
       // one row
       $query = "SELECT * FROM wine LIMIT 1";
       $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

       // Output a header, with headers spaced by padding
       print "\n" .
             str_pad("Field", 20) .
             str_pad("Type", 14) .
             str_pad("Null", 6) .
             str_pad("Key", 5) .
             str_pad("Extra", 12) . "\n";

       // How many attributes are there?
       $x = mysqli_num_fields($result);

       // for each of the attributes in the result set
       for($y=0;$y<$x;$y++)
       {
          // Get the meta-data for the attribute
          $info = mysqli_fetch_field ($result);

          // Print the attribute name
          print str_pad($info->name, 20);

          // Print the data type
          print str_pad($info->type, 6);

          // Print the field length in brackets e.g.(2)
          print str_pad("({$info->max_length})", 8);

          // Print out YES if attribute can be NULL
          if ($info->not_null != 1)
              print " YES ";
          else
              print "     ";

          // Print out selected index information
          if ($info->primary_key == 1)
             print " PRI ";
          elseif ($info->multiple_key == 1)
             print " MUL ";
          elseif ($info->unique_key == 1)
             print " UNI ";

          // If zero-filled, print this
          if ($info->zerofill)
             print " Zero filled";

          // Start a new line
          print "\n";
       }
       mysqli_free_result($result);
       mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
```

Comment: `str_pad`? why not just a table

Comment: check `$info` every iteration and see whats happening

Answer (score 0):

As per the query the expected result is the detail of the table structure and for that one can use mysql **Describe table** query which will provide the **structure** of the table.

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE NAME);
    $data = mysqli_query($con,"DESCRIBE tablename");
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Field</td>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td>Null</td>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Default</td>
        <td>Extra</td>
    </tr>
<?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['Field']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Type']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Null']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Key']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Default']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Extra']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

As per the query the expected result is the detail of the table structure and for that one can use mysql Describe table query which will provide the structure of the table.

Comment: As per the query the expected result is the detail of the table structure and for that one can use **mysql Describe table query** which will provide the **structure** of the table.

Comment: Please edit your answer and add this information to the answer. People may not read comments. :)

Answer (score -1):

you can try following code.I think it will help you.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$conn) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('winestore');
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM wine LIMIT 0,1');

if (!$result) {
die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
}
?>

<table>
<th>Field</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Null</th>
<th>Key</th>
<th>Extra</th>
<?php
/* get column metadata */
$i = 0;
while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result)) {
 $meta = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
if (!$meta) {
    echo "No information available<br />\n";
}
$i++;
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $meta->name;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $meta->type."(".$meta->max_length.")";?></td>
    <td><?php if($meta->not_null==1){echo 'NO';}else{echo 'YES';}?></td>
    <td><?php if($meta->multiple_key==1){ echo 'MUL';}if($meta->primary_key==1){echo 'PRI';}?></td>
    <td><?php echo $meta->not_null;?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

if you have any more doubt about this issue,please visit this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php

Comment: Mysql_* API has been removed. Use PDO instead